# ReactJS: how using queryselector variable out a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm using this code:

export default function Naviguation() {

```
const overBtnMenu = () => {
    const navBars = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-bars')
    for (let i = 0; i < navBars.length; i++) {
        navBars[i].style.width = '40px'
    }
}

const outBtnMenu = () => {
    const navBars = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-bars')
    navBars[0].style.width = '20px'
    navBars[1].style.width = '30px'
    navBars[2].style.width = '20px'
}

return (
    <nav>
        <img src={img} className='nav-logo' alt="logo" />
        <div className='nav-btn-menu' onMouseEnter={overBtnMenu} onMouseLeave={outBtnMenu}>
            <span className='nav-barTop nav-bars'></span>
            <span className='nav-barMiddle nav-bars'></span>
            <span className='nav-barBottom nav-bars'></span>
        </div>
    </nav>
)
```

}

the code runs correctly but I want to use the variable "navBars" once time like this

export default function Naviguation() {

```
const navBars = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-bars')

const overBtnMenu = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < navBars.length; i++) {
        navBars[i].style.width = '40px'
    }
}

const outBtnMenu = () => {
    navBars[0].style.width = '20px'
    navBars[1].style.width = '30px'
    navBars[2].style.width = '20px'
}

return (
    <nav>
        <img src={img} className='nav-logo' alt="logo" />
        <div className='nav-btn-menu' onMouseEnter={overBtnMenu} onMouseLeave={outBtnMenu}>
            <span className='nav-barTop nav-bars'></span>
            <span className='nav-barMiddle nav-bars'></span>
            <span className='nav-barBottom nav-bars'></span>
        </div>
    </nav>
)
```

}

But the code doesn't run because it wrote on the console "navBars undefined..."

How using a variable out the function to using it into my function?

Answer (score 0):

In React you have the concept of `useRef` whenever you need to get the value of an actual DOM element.

Rewrite your component as below:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Navigation() {
  const navBarsRef = useRef(null);
  const navBars = navBarsRef.current;

  useEffect(() => {
    navBarsRef.current = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-bars');
  }, []);

  const overBtnMenu = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < navBars.length; i++) {
      navBars[i].style.width = '40px';
    }
  };

  const outBtnMenu = () => {
    navBars[0].style.width = '20px';
    navBars[1].style.width = '30px';
    navBars[2].style.width = '20px';
  };

  return (
    <nav>
      <img src={img} className="nav-logo" alt="logo" />
      <div className="nav-btn-menu" onMouseEnter={overBtnMenu} onMouseLeave={outBtnMenu}>
        <span className="nav-barTop nav-bars"></span>
        <span className="nav-barMiddle nav-bars"></span>
        <span className="nav-barBottom nav-bars"></span>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I wrote your code:
```

import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import img from "../../images/logo-sanimex.webp";

```
import "./Naviguation.css";

export default function Navigation() {
  const navBarsRef = useRef(null);
  const navBars = navBarsRef.current;

  useEffect(() => {
    navBarsRef.current = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-bars');
  }, []);

  const overBtnMenu = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < navBars.length; i++) {
      navBars[i].style.width = '40px';
    }
  };

  const outBtnMenu = () => {
    navBars[0].style.width = '20px';
    navBars[1].style.width = '30px';
    navBars[2].style.width = '20px';
  };

  return (
    <nav>
      <img src={img} className="nav-logo" alt="logo" />
      <div className="nav-btn-menu" onMouseEnter={overBtnMenu} onMouseLeave={outBtnMenu}>
        <span className="nav-barTop nav-bars"></span>
        <span className="nav-barMiddle nav-bars"></span>
        <span className="nav-barBottom nav-bars"></span>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

But it's still not working :(

console.log shows:

    Uncaught TypeError: navBars is null
        overBtnMenu Naviguation.js:15
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution !! I just remove "null" from const navBarsRef = useRef()
Thanks very much for helping

```
import "./Naviguation.css";

export default function Navigation() {
  const navBarsRef = useRef();
  const navBars = navBarsRef.current;

  useEffect(() => {
    navBarsRef.current = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-bars');
  }, []);

  const overBtnMenu = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < navBars.length; i++) {
      navBars[i].style.width = '40px';
    }
  };

  const outBtnMenu = () => {
    navBars[0].style.width = '20px';
    navBars[1].style.width = '30px';
    navBars[2].style.width = '20px';
  };

  return (
    <nav>
      <img src={img} className="nav-logo" alt="logo" />
      <div className="nav-btn-menu" onMouseEnter={overBtnMenu} onMouseLeave={outBtnMenu}>
        <span className="nav-barTop nav-bars"></span>
        <span className="nav-barMiddle nav-bars"></span>
        <span className="nav-barBottom nav-bars"></span>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```